# Assign char value 'B' to byte datatype in soapUI

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soapui, soap-client

I have created a **web service** , Now i am trying to test my web service using **SaopUI** tool which takes **WSDL** file(xml file) as input

Here ,one of parameter is of **byte datatype**,it's value can be 'C' , 'S' , 'B'

I tried by pass value 'C' but it gives below error

**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C"**

I tried to pass ASCII value of 'C' as 67 but it gives below error

**The mandatory field of entityType either unassigned or NULL**

Please suggest how can I pass char value

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, you passed 'C' ( `char` ) as an input and not "C" (`String`) ? In any case, you can get a byte (a different datatype) with `"c".getBytes()[0]`, although this does not seem like the best solution

Comment: Hi @kcazllerraf , I am pass value like     <dat:entityType>C</dat:entityType>

Comment: @KiranChoudhary, can you a screen shot along with error? Have you tried validating the request by `Alt+v` in the request editor?

Comment: Hi @Rao , For [value = C] ,it is showing validation error : Invalid decimal value ,      For  [value = 67] , validation is OK

Comment: So, does request with value 67 get the desired response? If not, what is error on server side / client side?